# What is the type of `__str__` in a combined 2 and 3 code base?

Tags: python, mypy

I'm trying to convert this py2 class:

```
class Example(object):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(42)   # unicode(self.id)

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('u8')

    __repr__ = __str__
```

to a combined 2/3 version with types:

```
import sys
from typing import Text
from builtins import str as text

class Example(object):

    def _as_unicode(self):  # type: () -> Text
        return text(42)

    __unicode__ = _as_unicode

    def _as_bytes(self):  # type: () -> bytes
        return self._as_unicode().encode('utf-8')

    def __str__(self):  # type: () -> str
        if sys.version_info.major == 2:
            return self._as_bytes()      # line 17
        else:
            return self._as_unicode()    # line 19

    __repr__ = __str__
```

this produces the following errors:

```
c:\tmp> py -3 -m  mypy example.py
example.py:17: error: Incompatible return value type (got "bytes", expected "str")

c:\tmp> py -3 -m  mypy example.py -2
example.py:19: error: Incompatible return value type (got "unicode", expected "str")
```

Is there a way to convince mypy that the type of `__str__` is copacetic?
(and is there a better way to write this code in a 2 + 3 compatible way?)

Comment: What's the benefit of annotating magic methods?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think maybe you need to google mypy (hint: it's not pypy ;-)

Comment: @MichaelKolber there's nothing magical about dunder methods when it comes to types unless I'm missing something..?

Comment: It just seems as if `__str__()` should always return a `str`, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @MichaelKolber well, yes, that is the type I'm declaring `() -> str`, however that produces the errors listed in the question...

Comment: But you're not returning a string...

Comment: @MichaelKolber I'm not..?  I'm returning a Unicode value (of type `str`) in py3 and a single-byte-per-character-string (of type `str`) in py2... i.e. both are of type `str` in the Python version that runs them.

Comment: The Python 2 documentation for [`object.__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) says "The return value _must_ be a string object" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @martineau yes, I'm aware. In py2 `bytes is str` returns `True`.

Comment: Apparently mypy doesn't know that based on the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach here is actually not to try and find some kind of type that can bridge both Python versions, but instead get mypy to understand that your branches will run only on certain versions of Python.

To do this, change `sys.version_info.major == 2` into checks that look like this `sys.version_info[0] == 2`, for example:

```py
import sys
from typing import Text
from builtins import str as text

class Example(object):

    def _as_unicode(self):  # type: () -> Text
        return text(42)

    def _as_bytes(self):  # type: () -> bytes
        return self._as_unicode().encode('utf-8')

    def __str__(self):  # type: () -> str
        if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
            return self._as_bytes()
        else:
            return self._as_unicode()

    __unicode__ = _as_unicode
    __repr__ = __str__
```

This ends up side-stepping your problem entirely. E.g. since the "else" branch is marked as being unreachable when type-checking in Python 2.7 mode, mypy won't try analyzing that branch and so won't report the error.

If you want, you can go one step further and just do an if-else around the entire definition of `__str__`:

```py
import sys
from typing import Text
from builtins import str as text

class Example(object):

    def _as_unicode(self):  # type: () -> Text
        return text(42)

    def _as_bytes(self):  # type: () -> bytes
        return self._as_unicode().encode('utf-8')

    if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
        __str__ = _as_bytes
    else:
        __str__ = _as_unicode

    __unicode__ = _as_unicode
    __repr__ = __str__
```

Here's some [more info on the version and platform checks](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#version-and-platform-checks) mypy supports.

The fact that mypy doesn't understand specifically the form `sys.version_info.major` is likely an oversight. You could try filing an issue about this on [mypy's issue tracker](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues) (though idk how highly this one would be prioritized, given there are easy workarounds), or perhaps try adding support for this yourself by tinkering with the `consider_sys_version_info` function [in `mypy/reachability.py`](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/mypy/reachability.py#L112).